# Can I store slicers in a variable? (Pandas/Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm just wondering if I can do something like:

```
df.loc['1990':'2000']
```

by doing something like:

```
my_slice = '1990':'2000'
df.loc[my_slice]
```

What I've written doesn't work, but is there something similar that does?

Comment: You can create a `slice('1990', '2000')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you don't write slices like that. You write `slice('1900', '2000', None)` instead.

Comment: What's the 'None' part? (can't find slice in the docs) Thanks!

Comment: @cjm2671 that's the `step`, just like the `:` notation - `None` is the default, so redundant. As for the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice